# How do I change the colour of #region tokens in PowerShell ISE

Tags: customization, powershell-ise

I like to alter the default colour scheme of the PowerShell ISE, specifically to make the script pane "inverted", i.e. light text on a dark background. Comments are coloured PaleGreen:

```
[PS]> ($psise.Options.TokenColors) | ?{$_.Key -eq "Comment"} | FT -AutoSize

    Key Value    
    --- -----    
Comment #FF98FB98
```

I also like to use `#region ... #endregion` comments to allow me to collapse chunks of code.

When they are not collapsed, the `#region` and `#endregion` comments show in green like any other comment does, but once I collapse them they turn black, rendering them almost invisible on the dark background. Other sections (functions, etc.) don't chance colour when then they are collapsed.

Does anyone know if the colour of *collapsed* `#region` and `#endregion` comments can be set?

Comment: FWIW I'm in the same boat; it doesn't seem to have a visible setting in the options menu.

Comment: I'm assuming this is more of a bug in ISE which isn't getting too much attention as PS developers seem to be more keen on VS Code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the OP states in comments this appears to be a bug that, as of this moment, has still not been addressed. I was going to make one myself but there is already currently a [report on UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/18838177-collapsed-region-in-dark-mode-is-hardly-visible)!

Currently it seems the only way to get this fixed would be to give that report more traction. So like me, if you make your way here, vote on the proposed UserVoice post.

It is currently a survey which means that

> We saw this and we are considering it. Please upvote if it’s important to you.

So I would not consider it a waste of time.